# Installing mRemoteNG on Windows 8

Tags: windows, .net-framework, installation

When I try to install mremoteNG on Windows 8 i am getting mremoteng requires microsoft .net framework 3.0. When i download .net framework and start it cant Connect to internett. Any tips on how to install the serverapp on Windows 64bits?

Comment: Did you download the offline (standalone) installer for the .NET Framework?

Comment: nope. You have a link?

Answer (score 1):

Enable .NET 3.5 in the control panel then run your install again and you should be fine.

Full instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443.aspx

> You can also enable the **.NET Framework 3.5** yourself through `Control
>   Panel`. In `Control Panel`, choose `Programs and Features`, choose `Turn
>   Windows features on or off`, and then select the `.NET Framework 3.5
>   (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)` check box. This option requires an
>   Internet connection. You do not need to select the child items for
>   Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) HTTP activation unless you are
>   a developer who requires WCF script and handler mapping functionality.

Comment: Got the same errror by trying to enable from Control Panel. Windows couldn't connect to the Internet to download necessary files. Make sure that you're connected to the Internet, and click Retry to try again.” any other tips?

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?  Is there a firewall (hardware or software) or a/v program blocking the connection?  It should work fine unless something is blocking the download of the components.  Are you the sysadmin?

Answer (score 1):

1. Mount windows 8.1 iso (google around, there is a tool to download the ISO-file
2. Open  an elevated command prompt
3. Type: Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:E:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
   where Source is the path to your win-8.1-ISO-file